# pandas: read_csv how to force bool data to dtype bool instead of object

Tags: python, pandas

I'm reading in a large flatfile which has timestamped data with multiple columns. Data has a boolean column which can be True/False or can have no entry(which evaluates to nan).

When reading the csv the bool column gets typecast as object which prevents saving the data in hdfstore because of serialization error.

example data:

```
A    B    C    D
a    1    2    true
b    5    7    false
c    3    2    true
d    9    4
```

I use the following command to read

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv('data.csv', parse_dates=True)
```

One solution is to specify the dtype while reading in the csv but I was hoping for a more succinct solution like convert_objects where i can specify parse_numeric or parse_dates.

Comment: You have a missing value in your last row, this produces a mixed dtype, you should find that the first 3 rows are in fact boolean dtypes, what do you want to do with the missing value?

Comment: That is exactly my problem. The first three are in fact boolean. The data for D column is sparse. I'am ok with using a default value of false.

Comment: then calling `df['D'] = df['D'].fillna(False)` wil ensure the dtype for that column is homogenous

Comment: Does fillna take a dict which can render different default values to different columns? That would solve my use case as what i have presented is just a subset of the data. I'm sorry but the I couldn't get get this bit from the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)

Comment: haha I misread the question, thought it was asking to convert the file's column to `np.bool`

Comment: Yes you could pass a dict I'll post an answer to demonstrate

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you had a missing value in your csv the dtype of the columns is shown to be object as you have mixed dtypes, the first 3 row values are boolean, the last will be a float.

To convert the `NaN` value use [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html), it accepts a dict to map desired fill values with columns and produce a  homogeneous dtype:

```py
>>> t = """
A   B   C    D
a   1  NaN  true
b   5   7   false
c   3   2   true
d   9   4 """
>>> df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t),sep='\s+')
>>> df
   A  B   C    D
0  a  1  NaN  True
1  b  5   7   False
2  c  3   2   True
3  d  9   4   NaN
>>> df.fillna({'C':0, 'D':False})
   A  B  C   D
0  a  1  0  True
1  b  5  7  False
2  c  3  2  True
3  d  9  4  False
```

Comment: More precise on mapping `fillna()` by columns +1

Answer (score 9):

You can use `dtype`, it accepts a dictionary for mapping columns:

> ```
> dtype : Type name or dict of column -> type
>     Data type for data or columns. E.g. {'a': np.float64, 'b': np.int32}
> ```

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

# using your sample
csv_file = io.BytesIO('''
A    B    C    D
a    1    2    true
b    5    7    false
c    3    2    true
d    9    4''')

df = pd.read_csv(csv_file, sep=r'\s+', dtype={'D': np.bool})
# then fillna to convert NaN to False
df = df.fillna(value=False)

df 
   A  B  C      D
0  a  1  2   True
1  b  5  7  False
2  c  3  2   True
3  d  9  4  False

df.D.dtypes
dtype('bool')
```

Comment: This cleanly answers OP's question. A bit better might be to combine @EdChum's answer, specifically filling N/A with False only in column 'D': df.fillna({'D':False}). Generally, you don't want N/As in other columns set to False.

Answer (score 3):

From this [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41304332/pandas-read-csv-reading-a-boolean-with-missing-values-specified-as-an-int), I would suggest using converters kwarg:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv('data.csv',
            converters={'D': lambda x: True if x == 'true' else False})
```

as per your comment stating that NaN value should be replaced by False.

`converters` keyword argument can take a dictionary with keys being column names and values being functions to apply.